# How to disappear text or figures by printing?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, printing, ocg

As you know, the option `ocgcolorlinks` of the `hyperref` package disables **colors** of all links presented in a PDF file by printing it from Adobe Reader (and by compiling with e.g. **pdflatex**); as a result, they are printed in a default color.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to disable not the color, but entire text (of the link), i.e. that it would be completely disappeared on the printed paper?
2. Is it possible to do the same with an arbitrary text (i.e. not with the text of the link) or with an arbitrary figure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is the various `ocg*` packages, as this kind of features is referred to as »Optical Content Group«. You may want to try out [this](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf) trippy showcase. What's nice about this method is that the affected passages aren't simply turned white, but are disabled properly. So this is even going to work on a more sophisticated background (such as an image, a gradient fill, etc.).

This is an example using the `ocg-p` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ocg-p,hyperref}

\begin{document}
Print me!
\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{name}{id1}{1}
Print me! \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103824/}
\end{ocg}
\end{document}
```

Note the print preview:

[image: print preview with ocg-p]

Comment: Thank you! The `ocg-p` package is so fresh (of 2013) that I even couldn't find it initially among my MiKTeX packages. Synchronization rules! :)

Answer (score 5):

ad 1.:

> hrefhide – Sup­press hy­per-links when print­ing
>
> This LaTeX package provides the command \hrefdisplayonly (additionally
> to \href of the hyperref package). While the (hyperlinked) text
> appears like an ordinary \href in the compiled pdf-file, the same text
> will be "hidden" when printing the text. It is not really invisible,
> but just has the same color as the background (default: white).
> Therefore the layout is not changed when printing the document.
>
> Further the commands \hycon and \hycoff (hyper-colour-on/off) can be
> used to simulate switching option ocgcolorlinks of the hyperref
> package on and off.

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hrefhide

`hrefhide` as well as `ocg-p` (named in the [answer of Nils L](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103836/6865)) are possibly obsolete. Have a look at the `ocgx2` package at https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2.